# Which router to use in AngularJS 1.5

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-1.5, ngcomponentrouter

I am developing an AngularJS app on its 1.5 version, but i am confused about to use which routing component to use (`ngComponentRouter` or `ui-router`).

As, they are saying that `ngComponentRouter` has been depreated. And, my concern is that i can easily migrate my AngularJS app from 1.5 to 2.0 in near future.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go for ui-router as it is supported in angular2 also.

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/1.0.0-alpha.3/modules/ng2.html

Comment: Does Angular 2 router will have the same mechanism like `ui-router`?

Comment: Yes, angular 2 router is built on the top on ui-router

Comment: refrence: http://julienrenaux.fr/talks-src/2016/angular2-router-vs-ui-router/#/5/1